# Sharing Sharepoint SiteAssets using mapped network drive

Tags: sharepoint-server

I have Sharepoint site "SPSite" on server A, on server B I mapped drive to SiteAssets of SPSite.

I have an-other ASP.Net based web site on server B and I want to use images of SPSite i shared through mapped drive.  So I configured mapped SiteAssets folder as Virtual Directory on IIS for ASP.Net web site.

I do not have access to contents of folder SiteAssets throught my ASP.Net web site, looking for solution how can I configure the folder.

I'm not sure if I choose the right method for this task, if you can advise some alternative I can think about that.

Comment: Make sure that you grant required permissions to ASP.Net web site application pool user. Also maybe you can use SharePoint web services.

https://ktskumar.wordpress.com/2009/03/08/download-document-from-sharepoint-library-using-webservice/

Comment: ASP.Net is running under NetworkService Identity, other than mapped folder SiteAssets I can access everything